# Did Airbus bring back LAF (Load Alleviation Function) on A320s with Sharklets?

Tags: airbus-a320, airbus

I have heard that the A320 no longer has LAF (Load Alleviation Function) except for really old ones, but I also heard that A320s with Sharkelts do have LAF. So is it true that Airbus got rid of LAF on A320s and implemented it back on A320s with Sharklets, if so does anybody know why, because I heard Airbus says they go rid of it because it was not needed, so why would they add it back if they did? I heard it has something to do with that it increases MTOW (Maxium Takeoff Wight).

Comment: What are Sharklets?  Had to find a source - looks like curvier winglets than that is normally seen on jets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingtip_device#/media/File:Lufthansa_winglet_(14511808755).jpg

Comment: @CrossRoads you've got your answer by the looks of it, but for the record, they were also known as blended winglets on the 73NG.

Answer (score 1):

LAF is a function that alleviates load on wings roots, but was causing early wear to the actuators and to ailerons and spoilers hinges.

No LAF is not available on latest A320’s

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: LAF is installed on the latest skarklets, do you have any source for your info?